# Does Android JobScheduler or GCM JobScheduler persist jobs after an app update?

Tags: android

I know that both Android native (Post Lollipop) JobScheduler and GCM JobScheduler can persist jobs after a reboot, but what about after an app update? Will I still get the job invoked after the app is updated?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Regarding GCM Network Manager:

When Google Play Services or the client app is updated, all scheduled tasks will be removed. GcmNetworkManager invokes the client app’s onInitializeTasks(). Override this function to reschedule necessary tasks.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager

I have yet to find a similar requirement for JobScheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding JobScheduler:

No, the jobs do not get rescheduled after an update.

You could use a BroadcastReceiver with intent-filter for `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` and then schedule your job from there after an update.