# Do android scheduled jobs survive an app upgrade?

Tags: java, android, scheduled-tasks, upgrade, delayed-job

I would like to know whether Jobs scheduled using the JobScheduler Framework survive an app upgrade? I have a registered BroadcastReceiver listening to the

```
MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
```

intent. Do i need to reschedule a job in this case?

[Does Android JobScheduler or GCM JobScheduler persist jobs after an app update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108354/does-android-jobscheduler-or-gcm-jobscheduler-persist-jobs-after-an-app-update)

The link above leads to a similar question but does not have an answer so kindly do not mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know whether Jobs scheduled using the JobScheduler Framework survive an app upgrade?

Currently it is not. As you can see [in the issues of Firebase Job dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/6) (which internally uses same API), there is a issue opened "GooglePlayDriver: doesn't reschedule Jobs after App is updated".

Comment: thanks .. yea did that... i had a hunch that this was what was gonna happen.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a BroadcastReceiver with intent-filter actions `BOOT_COMPLETED` and `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACE` and then schedule your job from there. Or relay that event to a service...anything.

Comment: thanks .. yea did that... i had a hunch that this was what was gonna happen.